# Bootstrap form validation - Validate a form using an on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap form validation, and i want to validate my form using a button that is not inside the form tags.

The reasons i want to do that are:

1. I don't want to redirect the user to other page or reload the current page, after submiting the form.
2. I want to call to an ajax call that register a user and return an answer (fail/success).

How can I call the validate form mechanism and getting true or false in order to know if I can redirect to the ajax call.

Thank you.

Comment: *I want , i dont want* but  where is your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just attach a jquery click event to the button outside the form tags and inside that function do someting along the lines of:

```
//1) Submit Form using Form's ID
$("#testForm").submit();

//2 Submit Form using Form's Name
$("form[name='myForm']").submit();

//3 Submit Form using Form's Index.
$("form:first").submit();
```

Comment: That work's. how can i get a value (true/false) if the form validation passed or failed? I tried var form_check = $("#testForm").submit(); ,but i get an object and not a bool variable

Comment: Bootstrap is a css framework and dose not have any logic to interact with your back end or JavaScript responses. Just call some custom function on the success method of your ajax call and add the bootstrap classes using jquery addClass(). Here are all the classes: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation

Comment: Thank you, i solved it using a jquery code: var check_fields = 0 ;
    $("#RegForm .form-group").each(function(i , value) {        
     if( $(value).attr('class') == "form-group has-feedback has-error"){
      check_fields = 1 ;
  }

    });

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your field value as you want.
This is just basic form submission code in jquery.

```
 $("#yourformid" ).submit(function( event ) {
    var field1 = $('#field1').val();
    var field2 = $('#field2').val();

    var information = {
            'field1' : field1,
            'field2':field2,
    };
    var data = JSON.stringify(information);
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {value:data},
    url: "YOUR_URL",
    success: function(data) {
        if(data="sucess"){
        console.log(data)
        } else {
        console.log("Mission failed")

     }
    });

});
```